# Ext JS - How to Scroll to bottom of Textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

This is my code below. How can I scroll to bottom of textarea?
It must be something like

```
Ext.getCmp('output').setScrollPosition(Ext.getCmp('output').getScrollHeight());
```

Here is my code for the textarea:

```
var myWin= new Ext.Window({
            height        :    340,
            title        :    'CHAT',
            modal        :    true,
            resizable    :    false,
            draggable    :    false,
            closable     :    false,
            width        :    477,
            layout       : 'absolute',
            bodyStyle    :    'padding : 10px',
            buttonAlign  : 'center',
            items        :    [
            {
                id           :    'output',
                xtype        :    'textarea',
                width        :    216,
                readOnly     :    true,
                autoScroll   :    true,
                height       :    234,
                x            :    10,
                y            :    10
            },
            item6,
            {
                id       :    'input',
                xtype    :    'textfield',
                width    :    443,
                y        :    249,
                x        :    10
            }]
```

...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is ExtJs method to scroll textarea, however you can use HTML textarea properties:

```
var t = Ext.getCmp('output'),
   t1 = t.getEl().down('textarea');
t1.dom.scrollTop = 99999;
```

Here is the question where it was discussed: [Dynamically Scrolling a Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642353/dynamically-scrolling-a-textarea)

Comment: I modified your code: var t = Ext.getCmp('output'),
t1 = t.getEl();
t1.dom.scrollTop = 99999;

Comment: However, seems that it's not working in Google Chrome. I'm checking it.

Comment: Make sure that the component is rendered. Otherwise getEl() returns undefined. This worked for me: `if(t.rendered) t.getEl().down('textarea').dom.scrollTop = 99999;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = Ext.getCmp('output').getEl().down('textarea').dom;
d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight - d.offsetHeight;
```